# Python Selenium - Clicking css elements based on style attributes or containing text of child element? Twitter following

Tags: python, css, selenium, twitter

To clear up any confusion, my endgoal is to click all follow buttons of users I'm not already following.

Hello I've been hung up for a few hours on this and appreciate any input. I am attempting to click all buttons on a page that contain the text "Following" to avoid clicking buttons of users that I'm already following due to the nature of the markup and how clicking a button can both follow and unfollow a user.

Side note: The first button sibling element of "user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button" changes the display attribute from being display:none to display:block when the user is not already followed.

How would I go about accomplishing this task? I'm gettin a error when I attempt to click the item.

```
html_list = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".Grid--withGutter")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_css_selector(".follow-text")

for item in items:
item.click()
```

What has worked so far but does not differentiate from users already followed so it unfollows users I'm following already.

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.user-actions-follow-button')[count].click()
```

This is an example of a single button, the page will contain a few dozen of them.

```
<span class="user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button">
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--secondary EdgeButton--small button-text follow-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Follow</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Follow 
      <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--primary EdgeButton--small button-text following-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Following</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Following 
      <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--danger EdgeButton--small button-text unfollow-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Unfollow</span>
  <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Unfollow 
    <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--invertedDanger EdgeButton--small button-text blocked-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Blocked</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Blocked 
      <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--danger EdgeButton--small button-text unblock-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Unblock</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Unblock 
      <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--secondary EdgeButton--small button-text pending-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Pending</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Pending follow request from 
      <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="EdgeButton EdgeButton--secondary EdgeButton--small button-text cancel-text">
    <span aria-hidden="true">Cancel</span>
    <span class="u-hiddenVisually">Cancel your follow request to 
      <span class="username u-dir" dir="ltr">@<b>jefken11</b></span>
    </span>
  </button>
</span>
```

The error I receive:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dznutts/PycharmProjects/untitled/twitter_follow.py", line 142, in <module>
    browserWork()
  File "/home/dznutts/PycharmProjects/untitled/twitter_follow.py", line 115, in browserWork
    item.click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

Comment: "I'm gettin a error when I attempt to click the item."  What's the full error message with traceback?

Comment: Thanks for your time, have updated with the error.

Comment: In English, what are you trying to do? Follow all your followers or ??? I'm still confused as to what you are attempting.

Comment: I am attempting to follow all users who are not already followed.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to click all the visible `BUTTON`s that contain "Following X", those all have a CSS class of `following-text`. Why not use that?

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button.following-text")
visible_items = [item for item in items if item.is_displayed()]
for item in visible_items
    item.click()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'm very new with python. Going to give this a try and report back.

Comment: py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: 

tried it but no dice.

Comment: I think that's due to one of the elements not being visible, I've updated the code to filter the list of elements to only those that are visible. Try that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, will give this a shot and report back. <3

Comment: This code works but it still goes and clicks each follow button which results in unfollowing users previous followed and brings up the original issue.

Comment: Please post a link to the page you are looking at. This should work given the HTML you provided.

Comment: Sorry good idea, here is the page I am attempting to scrape. https://twitter.com/oldbob1944/followers

Comment: If you follow a few users, you can duplicate the problem where I unfollow ppl I've already followed while attempting to follow new people.

Comment: I looked at that page and there are no (visible) buttons that contain "Following" so what are you trying to do on this page?

Comment: Each and every button contains text, if the user is available to follow the text displayed is "follow" if not "unfollow".

Comment: <span aria-hidden="true">Follow</span>

Comment: OK. Your information is confusing. Your question states `I am attempting to click all buttons on a page that contain the text "Following"`. So are you actually trying to click buttons that contain "Following" or what? I went to the page you linked and paged down about 100 times and not a single button contains "Following". So... what is it exactly you are trying to do? Please edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I'm attempting to click all follow buttons, one at a time of users I'm not already following.